# Book - sci-fi - man watches alien land on top of mountain then goes on the alien's ship

Tags: story-identification, books

My sister and I must have read this book 10 times each in the 80s... I believe it belonged to our mother or father so it must have been written in the 50s-60s-70s.

Starts off with a discovery in the desert of a manuscript saying on a specific date an alien will land on a specific mountain. The protagonist goes and sees a spaceship land and an alien come out. That guy, I believe,  goes to a rock and touches it, and it flips to a computer. Anyway, I vaguely remember the protagonist ends up on the ship. He gets caught but sent to another primitive planet where he’s in charge of stopping two rival factions for war. He succeeds, has adventures, meets a girl, etc...

I’ve been looking for this book for 15 years now.

Comment: I don't know this book, but it sounds like something Piers Anthony wrote in the early years - shades of *Prostho Plus*.